# Thread variable lost / changed after passing thread object to another class?

Tags: multithreading, delphi

I wrote a little program that shows my problem:

```
unit Unit1;

interface

uses
  Winapi.Windows, Winapi.Messages, System.SysUtils, System.Variants, System.Classes, Vcl.Graphics,
  Vcl.Controls, Vcl.Forms, Vcl.Dialogs, Vcl.StdCtrls;

type
  TForm1 = class(TForm)
    Button1: TButton;
    procedure Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
  private
    { Private-Deklarationen }
  public
    { Public-Deklarationen }
  end;
  TThread_A = class(TThread)
    private
      stupidvariable : integer;
    protected
      procedure Execute; override;
    public
      property getstupidvar : integer read stupidvariable;
      constructor Create;
  end;

  TSomeClass = class
    private
      m_Obj : ^TThread_A;
      procedure readVar;
    public
      constructor Create(obj: TThread_A);
  end;

var
  Form1: TForm1;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

constructor TSomeClass.Create(obj: TThread_A);
begin
  m_Obj := @obj;
  readVar;
end;

procedure TSomeClass.readVar;
begin
  showmessage(inttostr(m_Obj.getstupidvar));
end;

constructor TThread_A.Create;
begin
  inherited Create(false);
  FreeOnTerminate := True;
end;

procedure TThread_A.Execute;
begin
  stupidvariable := 100;
end;

procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  threadA : TThread_A;
  someClass : TSomeClass;
begin
  threadA := TThread_A.Create;
  someClass := TSomeClass.Create(threadA);
end;

end.
```

What happens here exactly?
I thought I am passing the object "threadA" to someClass and assign the address of "threadA" to "m_Obj".

Why is the object lost?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
constructor TSomeClass.Create(obj: TThread_A);
begin
  m_Obj := @obj;
  readVar;
end;
```

Here `obj` is (in essence) a local variable, and so its lifetime ends when the function returns. Therefore you have remembered the address of something that no longer exists.

In fact you have too much indirection. Because `TThread_A` is a class, and classes are reference types, it is already a pointer. Change

```
m_Obj: ^TThread_A;
```

to

```
m_Obj: TThread_A;
```

and

```
m_Obj := @obj;
```

to

```
m_Obj := obj;
```

Now you are taking a copy of the reference to the instance, which is what I believe that you mean to do.

Not even that will leave you with a working program though. Because you set `FreeOnTerminate` the thread can be destroyed at any time. That means that you must not hold a reference to it since that reference can become invalid behind your back. So, you should also set `FreeOnTerminate` to `False`.

Not even that will leave you with predicatable outcome though. The thread procedure executes independently from the main thread. When you read the variable from the main thread, the thread may, or may not, have modified the variable. This is known as a data race. If you wish to wait until after the variable has been modified then you could use, for instance, an event object to allow the thread to signal that the variable is ready to be read.

Comment: That's exactly how I did it in the first place. But that still does not work. The variable is **0** on showmessage! Thanks for your answer however, I am really happy some one has a look on that.

Comment: There are multiple mistakes. You have to tackle them all. It would have been better if you had shown the original program before your trial and error "fixes" that introduced extra defects!

Comment: You mean, that showmessage could potentially get called before the variable is set to 100 in thread? In my main program that could not happen because the thread finishes before the object is passed to the other class. However, would you like to give me some keywords I could look up for the mistakes? Edit:// And yes, one problem was indeed that showmessage was called before the variable was set to 100 :D Thank you so much David!

Comment: I can't comment on your "main program" since I can't see it. But without some explicit synchronisation, don't make any assumptions about when the thread finishes. You might be running the program and observing that it always finishes first. But that does not mean it is guaranteed to do so. Without synchronisation, ordering is not predictable.

Comment: So I would do smth. like this: **property ImDone : bool read done;** and in procedure Execute; I would set **done** to true at the end for example and in the main thread I would wait in a loop until ImDone returns true? Would that be "okay" ? // Do you have a good example?

Comment: No. You'd use an event object. Or if you were waiting for the thread to complete you could wait on the thread itself. Or you could listen to the thread's OnTerminate event.